# Difference between Calendar.HOUR and Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY?

Tags: java, android, calendar

What is the difference between `Calendar.HOUR` and `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` ?
When to use `Calendar.HOUR` and `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` ?
I am confused sometime `Calendar.HOUR` this works fine and othertime `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` this works fine. What they return in the form of int? 
I have read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) documentation but not understood the difference.
Any suggestions
Thanks.

Comment: You have a perfect definition in the docs. See [HOUR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR) and [HOUR_OF_DAY](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY). In short, HOUR uses a 12-hour clock (am, pm) and HOUR_OF_DAY a 24-hour clock.

Comment: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android Joda time if you want to save your time!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR:

> Calendar.HOUR = Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.
>
> Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY = Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day. HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

Comment: Side note that the range for HOUR_OF_DAY is from 0 to 23 (inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

**This code will help you understand better**

`import java.util.Calendar; import java.util.GregorianCalendar;`

```
public class test{  public static void main(String[] args) {
  GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 8, 15, 21, 69,55);
```

//minutes = 69 is equal to 1 hour and 09 minutes. This hour will add to Hour place (21+1 = 22)//Sun Sep 15 22:09:55 IST 2013

```
  p(gc, Calendar.YEAR);    //gives year


  p(gc, Calendar.MONTH);   // gives month staring at 0 for  January


  p(gc, Calendar.DATE);    // date


  p(gc, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);// Sunday=1, Monday=2, .....Saturday -7


  p(gc, Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);//what week its running in week ,whether its first or second;


  p(gc, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);//In this case, How may times does Sunday is repeating in the month = 3;


  p(gc, Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);//count of the day in the year


  p(gc, Calendar.HOUR);//12 hour format. if the time is 22:09:55, answer would be (22-12)=10


  p(gc, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);// hour of day that is 22 (24h format)


  p(gc, Calendar.MINUTE);// 09


  p(gc, Calendar.SECOND);// 55


  
  System.out.println();
  
  System.out.println(gc.getTime());
```

}

```
static void p(Calendar c, int type) {
  System.out.print(c.get(type) + "-");
```

}
}

*output :

2013-8-15-1-3-3-258-10-22-9-55-

Sun Sep 15 22:09:55 IST 2013

*

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C70wi.png)           [Date visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Em2.png)