# getActualMinimum with HOUR as argument of Calendar returns 12 in Java

Tags: java, android, java-calendar

I'm trying to set the time of the `calendar` by calling the method `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR));` But `getActualMinimum(Calendar.HOUR)` returns 12 instead of 0.

Comment: Try to set: `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY` See [HOUR vs HOUR_OF_DAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37236381/difference-between-calendar-hour-and-calendar-hour-of-day)

Comment: @ADM because I used a time-milliseconds to date converter

Comment: @Vusal that's working, thank you

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: It seems you are only interested in a date? If so use a `LocalDate` from `java.time` and avoid the trouble with unexpected time of day. A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using  `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`  .

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes rather than the troubled legacy classes.

To get the first moment of a day, call [`LocalDate.atStartOfDay( ZoneId )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay(java.time.ZoneId)).

```
LocalDate.now(                       // Represent the date alone, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )      // Specify the time zone in which to determine the current date.
)
.withDayOfYear( 1 )                  // Or `.withDayOfMonth(1)` or `.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY) )`.
.atStartOfDay(                       // Determine the first moment of the day on that particular date in that particular zone.
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)                                    // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                         // Same moment, as seen in UTC.
.toEpochMilli()                      // Extract a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Getting the current date and time requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date and time vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only portion of that date-with-time.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

From that date, let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. Never assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) mean the day may start at another time such as 01:00:00.

The *java.time* classes use [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Rather than alter a property on an object (“mutate”), a fresh new object is created based on values of the original.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtResult = null ;
```

For your `switch` statement, use existing [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum. Because of an odd technical issue, the `switch` statement cannot use a qualified enum name. So we must use `YEARS` rather than `ChronoUnit.YEARS`, for example, as the switch variable. Use a static import to access the enum.

```
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit ;
…

switch ( unit ) {
    case YEARS : 
        zdtResult = ld.withDayOfYear( 1 )
                      .atStartOfDay( z ) ;
        break;

    case MONTHS : 
        zdtResult = ld.withDayOfMonth( 1 )
                      .atStartOfDay( z ) ;
        break;

    case WEEKS : 
        zdtResult = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY) )
                      .atStartOfDay( z ) ;
        break;

    default: …
}
```

From the resulting [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object to see that same moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdtResult.toInstant() ;
```

Your Question’s goal seems to be a count of milliseconds from the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC. I strongly suggest against using a mere `long` integer to track date-time values. Makes debugging and tracing troublesome, with bugs likely to escape notice. Pass around and store [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) objects instead.

But if you insist on the count, here's the code. Beware of data loss, as an `Instant` has a resolution of nanoseconds, so this call ignores any existing microseconds or nanoseconds.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMillis() ;
```

Notice how using *java.time* makes for code that is shorter, neater, and much more readable.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).